# Calling an Oracle stored procedure with Entity Framework and ODAC: "illegal variable name/number"

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have spent several hours trying to call an Oracle stored procedure but all my efforts have been unsuccessful.

This is the Oracle package header:

```
create or replace PACKAGE pqte_transacciones AS

PROCEDURE pr_creapedido
(
var_cliente     IN NUMBER,
var_usuario     IN NUMBER,
var_observacion IN VARCHAR2,
var_preciotot   IN VARCHAR2,
var_fechaent    IN VARCHAR2,
var_horaent     IN VARCHAR2,
var_fpago       IN VARCHAR2,
var_motivop     IN NUMBER,
var_conser_pre  IN NUMBER,
var_tipo_pedido IN VARCHAR2,
i_estado        IN NUMBER,
var_tipofrustrado IN VARCHAR2,
var_cuotas      IN NUMBER,
var_tventa      IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto1   IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad1   IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni1   IN NUMBER,
var_porcini1    IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle1    IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto2   IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad2   IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni2   IN NUMBER,
var_porcini2    IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle2    IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto3   IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad3   IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni3   IN NUMBER,
var_porcini3    IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle3    IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto4   IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad4   IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni4   IN NUMBER,
var_porcini4    IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle4    IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto5   IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad5   IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni5   IN NUMBER,
var_porcini5    IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle5    IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto6   IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad6   IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni6   IN NUMBER,
var_porcini6    IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle6    IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto7   IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad7   IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni7   IN NUMBER,
var_porcini7    IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle7    IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto8   IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad8   IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni8   IN NUMBER,
var_porcini8    IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle8    IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto9   IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad9   IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni9   IN NUMBER,
var_porcini9    IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle9    IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto10  IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad10  IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni10  IN NUMBER,
var_porcini10   IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle10   IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto11  IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad11  IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni11  IN NUMBER,
var_porcini11   IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle11   IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto12  IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad12  IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni12  IN NUMBER,
var_porcini12   IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle12   IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto13  IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad13  IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni13  IN NUMBER,
var_porcini13   IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle13   IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto14  IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad14  IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni14  IN NUMBER,
var_porcini14   IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle14   IN VARCHAR2,
var_producto15  IN VARCHAR2,
var_cantidad15  IN NUMBER,
var_valoruni15  IN NUMBER,
var_porcini15   IN VARCHAR2,
var_porclle15   IN VARCHAR2,
var_medio_pago  IN NUMBER,
var_orden_compra IN VARCHAR2,
var_ped_obs_sap IN VARCHAR2,
PEDIDO OUT NUMBER
);

end;
```

On the other hand, this is the call I am trying in C# (this is the full method which creates oracle parameters and then makes the actual call):

```
    public static decimal CreaPedido(decimal clienteID, decimal usuarioID, double valorTotal, string fechaeEntrega, string horaEntrega, 
                                     string formaPago, int medioPago, string ordenCompra,
                                     Producto[] productos)
    {
        decimal nuevoPedido = 0;
        try
        {
            using (LipigasEntities db = new LipigasEntities())
            {
                ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();
                OracleParameter var_cliente = new OracleParameter("var_cliente", OracleDbType.Decimal);
                var_cliente.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_cliente.Value = clienteID;
                OracleParameter var_usuario = new OracleParameter("var_usuario", OracleDbType.Decimal);
                var_usuario.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_usuario.Value = usuarioID;
                OracleParameter var_observacion = new OracleParameter("var_observacion", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                var_observacion.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_observacion.Value = String.Empty;
                OracleParameter var_preciotot = new OracleParameter("var_preciotot", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                var_preciotot.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_preciotot.Value = valorTotal.ToString();
                OracleParameter var_fechaent = new OracleParameter("var_fechaent", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                var_fechaent.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_fechaent.Value = fechaeEntrega;
                OracleParameter var_horaent = new OracleParameter("var_horaent", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                var_horaent.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_horaent.Value = horaEntrega;
                OracleParameter var_fpago = new OracleParameter("var_fpago", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                var_fpago.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_fpago.Value = formaPago;
                OracleParameter var_motivop = new OracleParameter("var_motivop", OracleDbType.Int32);
                var_motivop.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_motivop.Value = (int)Constants.Motivos.SinInformacion;
                OracleParameter var_conser_pre = new OracleParameter("var_conser_pre", OracleDbType.Int32);
                var_conser_pre.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_conser_pre.Value = 0;
                OracleParameter var_tipo_pedido = new OracleParameter("var_tipo_pedido", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                var_tipo_pedido.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_tipo_pedido.Value = String.Empty;
                OracleParameter i_estado = new OracleParameter("i_estado", OracleDbType.Int32);
                i_estado.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; i_estado.Value = (int)Constants.Estados.Tomado;
                OracleParameter var_tipofrustrado = new OracleParameter("var_tipofrustrado", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                var_tipofrustrado.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_tipofrustrado.Value = String.Empty;
                OracleParameter var_cuotas = new OracleParameter("var_cuotas", OracleDbType.Int32);
                var_cuotas.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_cuotas.Value = 0;
                OracleParameter var_tventa = new OracleParameter("var_tventa", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                var_tventa.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_tventa.Value = String.Empty;
                OracleParameter[] var_productos = new OracleParameter[15];
                OracleParameter[] var_cantidades = new OracleParameter[15];
                OracleParameter[] var_valoresUnitarios = new OracleParameter[15];
                OracleParameter[] var_porcinis = new OracleParameter[15];
                OracleParameter[] var_porclles = new OracleParameter[15];
                for(int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
                {
                    Producto producto = productos.Skip(i - 1).FirstOrDefault();
                    var_productos[i - 1] = new OracleParameter(String.Concat("var_producto", i), OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                    var_productos[i - 1].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_productos[i - 1].Value = producto == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)producto.Descripcion;
                    var_cantidades[i - 1] = new OracleParameter(String.Concat("var_cantidad", i), OracleDbType.Int32);
                    var_cantidades[i - 1].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_cantidades[i - 1].Value = producto == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)producto.Cantidad;
                    var_valoresUnitarios[i - 1] = new OracleParameter(String.Concat("var_valoruni", i), OracleDbType.Int32);
                    var_valoresUnitarios[i - 1].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_valoresUnitarios[i - 1].Value = producto == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)producto.ValorUnitario;
                    var_porcinis[i - 1] = new OracleParameter(String.Concat("var_porcini", i), OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                    var_porcinis[i - 1].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_porcinis[i - 1].Value = DBNull.Value;
                    var_porclles[i - 1] = new OracleParameter(String.Concat("var_porclle", i), OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                    var_porclles[i - 1].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_porclles[i - 1].Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                OracleParameter var_medio_pago = new OracleParameter("var_medio_pago", OracleDbType.Int32);
                var_medio_pago.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_medio_pago.Value = medioPago;
                OracleParameter var_orden_compra = new OracleParameter("var_orden_compra", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                var_orden_compra.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_orden_compra.Value = ordenCompra;
                OracleParameter var_ped_obs_sap = new OracleParameter("var_ped_obs_sap", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                var_ped_obs_sap.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; var_ped_obs_sap.Value = String.Empty;
                OracleParameter p_pedido = new OracleParameter("PEDIDO", OracleDbType.Decimal);
                p_pedido.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

                string sql = @"begin
                                 pqte_transacciones_pr_creapedido
                                             (:var_cliente, :var_usuario, :var_observacion, :var_preciotot, 
                                              :var_fechaent, :var_horaent, :var_fpago, :var_motivop, :var_conser_pre, 
                                              :var_tipo_pedido, :i_estado, :var_tipofrustrado, :var_cuotas, :var_tventa,
                                              :var_producto1, :var_cantidad1, :var_valoruni1, :var_porcini1, :var_porclle1,
                                              :var_producto2, :var_cantidad2, :var_valoruni2, :var_porcini2, :var_porclle2, 
                                              :var_producto3, :var_cantidad3, :var_valoruni3 :var_porcini3, :var_porclle3, 
                                              :var_producto4, :var_cantidad4, :var_valoruni4, :var_porcini4, :var_porclle4, 
                                              :var_producto5, :var_cantidad5, :var_valoruni5, :var_porcini5, :var_porclle5, 
                                              :var_producto6, :var_cantidad6, :var_valoruni6, :var_porcini6, :var_porclle6, 
                                              :var_producto7, :var_cantidad7, :var_valoruni7, :var_porcini7, :var_porclle7, 
                                              :var_producto8, :var_cantidad8, :var_valoruni8, :var_porcini8, :var_porclle8, 
                                              :var_producto9, :var_cantidad9, :var_valoruni9, :var_porcini9, :var_porclle9, 
                                              :var_producto10, :var_cantidad10, :var_valoruni10, :var_porcini10, :var_porclle10, 
                                              :var_producto11, :var_cantidad11, :var_valoruni11, :var_porcini11, :var_porclle11, 
                                              :var_producto12, :var_cantidad12, :var_valoruni12, :var_porcini12, :var_porclle12, 
                                              :var_producto13, :var_cantidad13, :var_valoruni13, :var_porcini13, :var_porclle13, 
                                              :var_producto14, :var_cantidad14, :var_valoruni14, :var_porcini14, :var_porclle14, 
                                              :var_producto15, :var_cantidad15, :var_valoruni15, :var_porcini15, :var_porclle15,
                                              :var_medio_pago, :var_orden_compra, :var_ped_obs_sap, :PEDIDO);
                               end;";
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,
                                              var_cliente, var_usuario, var_observacion, var_preciotot, 
                                              var_fechaent, var_horaent, var_fpago, var_motivop, var_conser_pre, 
                                              var_tipo_pedido, i_estado, var_tipofrustrado, var_cuotas, var_tventa,
                                              var_productos[0], var_cantidades[0], var_valoresUnitarios[0], var_porcinis[0], var_porclles[0],
                                              var_productos[1], var_cantidades[1], var_valoresUnitarios[1], var_porcinis[1], var_porclles[1],
                                              var_productos[2], var_cantidades[2], var_valoresUnitarios[2], var_porcinis[2], var_porclles[2],
                                              var_productos[3], var_cantidades[3], var_valoresUnitarios[3], var_porcinis[3], var_porclles[3],
                                              var_productos[4], var_cantidades[4], var_valoresUnitarios[4], var_porcinis[4], var_porclles[4],
                                              var_productos[5], var_cantidades[5], var_valoresUnitarios[5], var_porcinis[5], var_porclles[5],
                                              var_productos[6], var_cantidades[6], var_valoresUnitarios[6], var_porcinis[6], var_porclles[6],
                                              var_productos[7], var_cantidades[7], var_valoresUnitarios[7], var_porcinis[7], var_porclles[7],
                                              var_productos[8], var_cantidades[8], var_valoresUnitarios[8], var_porcinis[8], var_porclles[8],
                                              var_productos[9], var_cantidades[9], var_valoresUnitarios[9], var_porcinis[9], var_porclles[9],
                                              var_productos[10], var_cantidades[10], var_valoresUnitarios[10], var_porcinis[10], var_porclles[10],
                                              var_productos[11], var_cantidades[11], var_valoresUnitarios[11], var_porcinis[11], var_porclles[11],
                                              var_productos[12], var_cantidades[12], var_valoresUnitarios[12], var_porcinis[12], var_porclles[12],
                                              var_productos[13], var_cantidades[13], var_valoresUnitarios[13], var_porcinis[13], var_porclles[13],
                                              var_productos[14], var_cantidades[14], var_valoresUnitarios[14], var_porcinis[14], var_porclles[14],
                                              var_medio_pago, var_orden_compra, var_ped_obs_sap, p_pedido);

                nuevoPedido = ((OracleDecimal)p_pedido.Value).Value;
                ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLog.Save(ex);
        }

        return nuevoPedido;
    }
```

The application throws an exception at line with db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand method call.

The exception is: "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"

What do you see wrong in this code?

Oracle.DataAccess.dll version is: 4.112.3.0

Comment: Maybe instead of defining 5 times 15 individual parameters, you should consider to use [PL/SQL Associative Array Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featOraCommand.htm#BABBDHBB). Then you would have to define only 5 parameters once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma in the `sql` string assignment in the C# code, specifically after `:var_valoruni3` - add it and see if it works. If it doesn't, there may be other things missing as well.

Comment: Thanks.... when I added the comma, the error changed, but showing that I have separated the package name and the procedure by an underscore. I changed to be a dot. That way, the procedure is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a period between the name of the package and the name of the procedure when you invoke it. Right now you have

```
string sql = @"begin
                 pqte_transacciones_pr_creapedido
```

Change it to

```
string sql = @"begin
                 pqte_transacciones.pr_creapedido
```

Best of luck